# Installing 'stats', 'visualize' packages to R 3.2.2

Tags: r

I am unable to install `stats` and `visualize` packages on windows. I am using R version 3.2.2.

Any suggestions??

Regards

Comment: You should add the errors you get when you try to install them plus the code you used.

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘stats’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

but the documentation of 'stats' package mentions it for R 3.2.2

Comment: `stats` is included in base-R. Type `library(stats)` and you ll see it. Also, you should edit your question to add the error/warning, you shoudn't add it in the comments.